Issue with Hazelcast_Blueprint.xml while using KARAF
While deploying the Hazelcast_Blueprint.xml file for setting up a Talend webservice in Karaf, i am getting the below error:
tadmin@trun()> bundle:diag Hazelcast_Blueprint.xml
Bundle 3167
Status: Failure
Blueprint
Exception:
Error when instantiating bean #recipe-11 of class com.hazelcast.config.FileSystemXmlConfig
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instantiating bean #recipe-11 of class com.hazelcast.config.FileSystemXmlConfig
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.wrapAsCompDefEx(BeanRecipe.java:362)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromType(BeanRecipe.java:352)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:283)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:685)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:666)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:108)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:268)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:685)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:666)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:81)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:90)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:360)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:190)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:737)
The file already contains a correct pointer to the hazelcast.xml.
I am stuck into this from last two days. Would appreciate if someone could provide some help here.
Thanks in advance!
I tried to deploy the upgraded version of hazelcast jar, but it didn't help. The dependent bundles already seem to be fine. But would appreciate if anyone could ask for a dependent bundle that i might have missed.
